Disjoint predicates FOL: equivalence of normal forms
I'm interested in exploring a restriction of first-order logic (FOL) where each predicate is disjoint. Formally, for any predicates Pᵢ and Pⱼ where i ≠ j, we enforce the following condition:
¬∃x (Pᵢ(x) ∧ Pⱼ(x))
Problem
Given this restriction, I want to know if normal forms of these formulas are semantically equivalent if and only if they are syntactically equivalent.
Clarifications and Examples
By "normal forms," I mean any standard form of first-order logic such as Prenex + Conjunctive Normal Form (CNF) or Disjunctive Normal Form (DNF).
Here are some formulas that adhere to this restricted version of FOL:

¬∃x (P(x) ∧ Q(x)) → (Q(y) ∧ P(w))
¬∃x (P(x) ∧ Q(x)) → (P(y) ∨ Q(w))
¬∃x₁ (P(x₁) ∧ Q(x₁)) ∧ ¬∃x₂ (P(x₂) ∧ R(x₂)) ∧ ¬∃x₃ (Q(x₃) ∧ R(x₃)) → (R(y) ∨ Q(w))

On the other hand, the following formula is unacceptable because it doesn't incorporate the disjoint predicate requirement:
Q(y) ∧ P(w)
This restriction is similar to many-sorted logic, where each predicate corresponds to a unique "sort." However, unlike many-sorted logic, we only allow a single predicate for each "sort," although comparisons between different sorts are syntactically valid.

Could you please just convert this to unicode - it's rather difficult to read - this site doesn't seem to format LaTeX.

mudskipper - done. Thank you for pointing this out.

If I understand this right, you are only considering monadic predicate calculus. Are you using the convention that 'free' variables are universally quantified? And how can a formula incorporate or not incorporate your requirement when it is semantic and depends on your predicates' truth sets  in a given interpretation? Generally, this sounds like a technical mathematical logic question that you will probably get better feedback on on MathSE or MathOverflow.

I’m studying normal forms in the context of Boolean algebra right now, I can’t answer your question but thought I’d still try to respond to some of it. > I'm interested in exploring a restriction of first-order logic (FOL) where each predicate is disjoint. So anything fulfilling a predicate P() cannot also fulfill a predicate Q(), therefore every element fulfills a maximum of one predicate? > Given this restriction, I want to know if normal forms of these formulas are semantically equivalent if and only if they are syntactically equivalent. Two formulae are semantically equivalent if they have

Ok let's try break it down Disjoint Predicates Your restriction implies that predicates Pᵢ and Pⱼ where i ≠ j cannot simultaneously be true for the same element. This is expressed as:
¬∃x(Pi(x)∧Pj(x))¬∃x(Pi​(x)∧Pj​(x)) Normal Forms Normal forms, such as Prenex Conjunctive Normal Form (CNF) or Disjunctive Normal Form (DNF), are standardized ways of expressing logical formulas. Semantic vs. Syntactic Equivalence Two formulas are semantically equivalent if they have the same truth value in every model. But two formulas are syntactically equivalent if they are identical in form. **Prob

I’m voting to close this question because it's technical, not philosophical.
